# Can I change the aesthetics for textareas in Ruby just by using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just like the title says. I was just wondering since I am really new to Ruby. I tried a lot such as:

```
<%= password_field_tag :Password, :class=>"textArea1"%>
<%= password_field_tag :Password, :class=>'textArea1'%>
<%= password_field_tag :Password, :html=>{:class=>"textArea1"%>
<%= password_field_tag :Password, :html=>{:class=>'textArea1'%>
```

but it still does not work.
By the way, this is my other codes:

```
    <%= form_tag :login do %>

    <%= label_tag :Username %><br />
   <%= text_field_tag :Login, params[:Login] %>

    <%= label_tag :Password %><br/>
    <%= password_field_tag :Password, :class=>"textArea1"%>

  <%= submit_tag "Log in" %>
```

and my css:

```
div.textArea1   {
padding: 7px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px #dddddd;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px #dddddd;
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px
}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter in what server side technology you code (Ruby, ASP.NET or whatever), coz, finally when the page is rendered by your browser, it is in HTML, CSS and JS. That means, if you are able to specify the class name on the elements, then you can use the class name to target the styles with CSS.

What I note from your code is that you say

```
div.textArea1{
....
}
```

That means, the styles entered inside that will work only if the element with class 'textArea1' is a div. In the above case, you have used a password field.

In other words, try this (to target all input elements with class 'textArea1'):

```
input.textArea1{
....
}
```

or simply this (to target all input html elements with class 'textArea1'

```
.textArea1{
....
}
```

How to add class to a form?

This is the way to add class and id:

```
<% form_tag :id => 'myid' :class => 'myclass' do -%>
...
<% end -%>
```

Having said that, understand that 'form' is a HTML element, 'input' (such as your 'text_field_tag') is another HTML element.

So, if you want to style all the 'input' elements inside your form with class attribute 'myclass', you need to use this CSS selector:

```
form.myclass input{
....
}
```

Suggest you learn about HTML elements and CSS selector basics from http://www.w3schools.com to understand what is generated by server side coding languages (such as Ruby)

Comment: Can I ask what is the proper way to declare the class inside the form_tag? Because I use:  :class=>"textArea1", but it did not work, together with input.textArea1 or .textArea1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Rails API reference for [`password_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-password_field_tag). You can't really start passing `options` the way you're trying until you've provided values for the arguments that precede it.

Your call to `password_field_tag` is missing the 2nd argument for `value`.

```
<%= password_field_tag :Password, '', :class => "textArea1" %>
```

I bet that will solve it for you. But if that doesn't, update your question to show what the generated HTML looks like for that password input.